# Uncaught ReferenceError: GBrowserIsCompatible is not defined

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, google-maps

Am getting error:Uncaught ReferenceError: GBrowserIsCompatible is not defined.
i have function in js file which am loading on document .ready() event.

```
if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
       //do somthing
    }
```

am loading js file using:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getScript("test.js", function(){
               alert("Script loaded and executed.");
             });
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How are you loading the API? Are you using the deprecated (and turned off) [Google Maps Javascript API v2](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-maps-api-2/info)? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of possible reasons for this 
1. Can you verify you have load the Google Maps API with **your validated API key**. [Check this](https://developers.google.com/maps/signup?csw=1) for same.

```
<script src='http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=My_API_KEY'></script>
```

2. Also what is possible is **you are checking for it early**. Try something like

```
    var iterations=0;
    function checksIfscriptIsLoaaded()
    {
      if (typeof GBrowserIsCompatible === 'undefined')
      {
        setTimeout(ChecksIfscriptIsLoaaded, 1000);
        iterations++;//you want to do this finite number of times say 10.
      }
      else 
      {
        if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
           //do your thing
         } else {
            alert('browser is not supported.');
         }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

`GBrowserIsCompatible()` is deprecated and since v3 has been removed from API. There's no need to use this check in v3.

From [guide for upgrading from v2 to v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2tov3#comparing-code):

> The `GBrowserIsCompatible()` and `GUnload()` methods are no longer required in v3, and have been removed from the API

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @barbsan,Thanks the answer is edited now. I just was working on the same problem. Found out about this, thought it may help future googlers. Cheers.

Comment: @ansuman I've edited your answer based on your edit, feel free to rollback, but you should focus on methods included in question, it doesn't matter that you can find `GBrowserIsCompatible` somewhere in the middle of the page in your link